# Determine if integer can be factored as $ab(a+b)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, factoring

For $N,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and distinct $a,b>1$, how can I determine if it is possible to factor $N$ as any $a \times b \times (a+b)$? (I don't necessarily need all $a,b$ if that helps...)

My first thought was to factor $N$, then enumerate the factors into three buckets, $a$, $b$, and \$leftover, then check if \$leftover equals $a+b$. But this grows quite badly, for n total factors ~ $\mathcal{O}(n!)$ ([OEIS A200978](https://oeis.org/A200978)), so this approach seems infeasible.

Comment: As far as enumerating factors goes: you only need to check factors $a$ and $b$ up to $\sqrt{N}$. Unsure how much that helps, however.

Comment: $N=a\times b\times(a+b)$ must be even

Comment: It is not nearly that bad.  The OEIS sequence considers the order of books on each shelf, while you only care what factors go into $a$ and $b$.  $554400$ has $216$ factors and has more than any smaller number.  You just select one of those for $a$, a factor of what is left for $b$, which has less than $216$ choices, and check the result.

Comment: The sequence http://oeis.org/A088915 gives them without requiring $a,b$ distinct, so has $2$ and $16$ which you do not want.

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A088915 -- Nonnegative numbers of the form mn(m+n) with integers m,n

Comment: My crude line of thinking. 1) Looks like a cubic equation in two unknowns. 2) Therefore we are likely to need elliptic curves. 3) Therefore "a lot will be known", but "the question is difficult (if not impossible) to settle with elementary methods".

Comment: Interesting facts about this are that if $(a,b)$ is a solution then so are $(b,a)$, $(a,-a-b)$. If you compose those you find a group of solutions isomorphic to $S_3$. Plus @JyrkiLahtonen's elliptic curve is $x=4N/b$, $y=4N(2a+b)/b$, $y^2=x^3+16n^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Sophie. I think you could flesh that comment out to an answer :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I don't want to post as an answer because while I can find the solutions with sage for each $N$, I don't know anything about it for $N$ in general.

Comment: Understood @Sophie. I just suspect that what you observed may be the most that can be said, in which case it might make sense to use it as an answer. But, those curves may belong to a family, where more is known. May be wait for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix the value of $a$, you have a simple quadratic equation $b(b+a) = \tfrac{N}{a}$ with $b$ the unknown, you can solve it to get two possible values, then you check if any of those are natural numbers and divisors of $N$. So to find out if such $a$ and $b$ exist, you need to check all values of $a$ which are divisors of $N$, and for every such $a$ find $b$.

For a number with $k$ divisors this algorithm's complexity is $O(k) + O(factorize(N))$ where $factorize(N)$ is complexity of factorizing a number.

Answer (score 3):

First note that $ab(a+b)=n$ implies

$$a(-a-b)(a+(-a-b))=n$$

and so $(a,-a-b)$ is also a solution, plus obviously $(b,a)$ by symmetry. If you compose them you get a group of 6 possible solutions but sometimes they overlap. That group happens to be isomorphic to $S_3$. To transform into an elliptic curve let $q=\frac a b$ then

$$b^3q(q+1)=n$$

$$q^2+q=nb^{-3}$$

$$(2q+1)^2=1+4nb^{-3}$$

$$(4n(2q+1))^2=16n^2+\left(\frac{4n}b\right)^3$$

Let $y=4n(2q+1)$ and $x=\frac{4n}b$ and we have an elliptic curve

$$y^2=x^3+16n^2$$

And the reverse transform is $a=\frac{y-4n}{2x}$, $b=\frac{4n}x$. This curve has the trivial points $(x,y)=(0,\pm 4n)$. Those points sum to the identity so call them $\pm P$, we have that $P+P=-P$ so they're elements of order 3. I did a bit of computation with sage:

```
for i in range(1,100): 
    print(i, EllipticCurve([0,0,0,0,16*i^2]).torsion_points(), EllipticCurve([0,0,0,0,16*i^2]).gens())                                                                                                               
1 [(0 : -4 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 4 : 1)] []
2 [(-4 : 0 : 1), (0 : -8 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 8 : 1), (8 : -24 : 1), (8 : 24 : 1)] []
3 [(0 : -12 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 12 : 1)] []
4 [(0 : -16 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 16 : 1)] []
5 [(0 : -20 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 20 : 1)] []
6 [(0 : -24 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 24 : 1)] [(-8 : 8 : 1)]
7 [(0 : -28 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 28 : 1)] [(8 : 36 : 1)]
8 [(0 : -32 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 32 : 1)] []
9 [(0 : -36 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 36 : 1)] [(-8 : 28 : 1)]
10 [(0 : -40 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 40 : 1)] []
11 [(0 : -44 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 44 : 1)] []
12 [(0 : -48 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 48 : 1)] [(-12 : 24 : 1)]
13 [(0 : -52 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 52 : 1)] [(273 : 4511 : 1)]
14 [(0 : -56 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 56 : 1)] []
15 [(0 : -60 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 60 : 1)] [(24 : 132 : 1)]
16 [(-16 : 0 : 1), (0 : -64 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 64 : 1), (32 : -192 : 1), (32 : 192 : 1)] []
17 [(0 : -68 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 68 : 1)] [(8568 : 793084 : 1)]
18 [(0 : -72 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 72 : 1)] []
19 [(0 : -76 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 76 : 1)] [(24 : 140 : 1), (1824 : 77900 : 1)]
20 [(0 : -80 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 80 : 1)] [(-16 : 48 : 1)]
21 [(0 : -84 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 84 : 1)] []
22 [(0 : -88 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 88 : 1)] [(48 : 344 : 1)]
23 [(0 : -92 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 92 : 1)] []
24 [(0 : -96 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 96 : 1)] []
25 [(0 : -100 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 100 : 1)] []
26 [(0 : -104 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 104 : 1)] [(12 : 112 : 1)]
27 [(0 : -108 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 108 : 1)] []
28 [(0 : -112 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 112 : 1)] [(-12 : 104 : 1)]
29 [(0 : -116 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 116 : 1)] []
30 [(0 : -120 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 120 : 1)] [(-24 : 24 : 1), (-20 : 80 : 1)]
31 [(0 : -124 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 124 : 1)] [(8905/441 : 1422989/9261 : 1)]
32 [(0 : -128 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 128 : 1)] []
33 [(0 : -132 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 132 : 1)] [(-24 : 60 : 1)]
34 [(0 : -136 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 136 : 1)] [(-16 : 120 : 1)]
35 [(0 : -140 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 140 : 1)] [(-24 : 76 : 1)]
36 [(0 : -144 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 144 : 1)] []
37 [(0 : -148 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 148 : 1)] [(48 : 364 : 1), (4440 : 295852 : 1)]
38 [(0 : -152 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 152 : 1)] []
39 [(0 : -156 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 156 : 1)] []
40 [(0 : -160 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 160 : 1)] []
41 [(0 : -164 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 164 : 1)] []
42 [(0 : -168 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 168 : 1)] [(-24 : 120 : 1)]
43 [(0 : -172 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 172 : 1)] [(2408 : 118164 : 1)]
44 [(0 : -176 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 176 : 1)] []
45 [(0 : -180 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 180 : 1)] []
46 [(0 : -184 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 184 : 1)] []
47 [(0 : -188 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 188 : 1)] []
48 [(0 : -192 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 192 : 1)] [(-32 : 64 : 1)]
49 [(0 : -196 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 196 : 1)] [(1617 : 65023 : 1)]
50 [(0 : -200 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 200 : 1)] [(24 : 232 : 1)]
51 [(0 : -204 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 204 : 1)] [(144 : 1740 : 1)]
52 [(0 : -208 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 208 : 1)] []
53 [(0 : -212 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 212 : 1)] [(13620672/47089 : 50315372428/10218313 : 1)]
54 [(-36 : 0 : 1), (0 : -216 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 216 : 1), (72 : -648 : 1), (72 : 648 : 1)] []
55 [(0 : -220 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 220 : 1)] []
56 [(0 : -224 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 224 : 1)] [(32 : 288 : 1)]
57 [(0 : -228 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 228 : 1)] []
58 [(0 : -232 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 232 : 1)] [(-24 : 200 : 1)]
59 [(0 : -236 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 236 : 1)] []
60 [(0 : -240 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 240 : 1)] []
61 [(0 : -244 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 244 : 1)] [(80 : 756 : 1)]
62 [(0 : -248 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 248 : 1)] [(-308/9 : 3952/27 : 1)]
63 [(0 : -252 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 252 : 1)] [(16 : 260 : 1)]
64 [(0 : -256 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 256 : 1)] []
65 [(0 : -260 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 260 : 1)] [(-40 : 60 : 1), (-39 : 91 : 1)]
66 [(0 : -264 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 264 : 1)] []
67 [(0 : -268 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 268 : 1)] [(-25865696/1750329 : 606501324260/2315685267 : 1)]
68 [(0 : -272 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 272 : 1)] [(240 : 3728 : 1)]
69 [(0 : -276 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 276 : 1)] [(-23 : 253 : 1)]
70 [(0 : -280 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 280 : 1)] [(-40 : 120 : 1)]
71 [(0 : -284 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 284 : 1)] [(99288/1849 : 38582996/79507 : 1)]
72 [(0 : -288 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 288 : 1)] [(-32 : 224 : 1)]
73 [(0 : -292 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 292 : 1)] []
74 [(0 : -296 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 296 : 1)] []
75 [(0 : -300 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 300 : 1)] [(-24 : 276 : 1)]
76 [(0 : -304 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 304 : 1)] []
77 [(0 : -308 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 308 : 1)] []
78 [(0 : -312 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 312 : 1)] [(-39 : 195 : 1)]
79 [(0 : -316 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 316 : 1)] [(3081/4 : 171035/8 : 1)]
80 [(0 : -320 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 320 : 1)] []
81 [(0 : -324 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 324 : 1)] []
82 [(0 : -328 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 328 : 1)] []
83 [(0 : -332 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 332 : 1)] []
84 [(0 : -336 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 336 : 1)] [(-48 : 48 : 1)]
85 [(0 : -340 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 340 : 1)] [(-15 : 335 : 1)]
86 [(0 : -344 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 344 : 1)] [(-48 : 88 : 1), (504 : 11320 : 1)]
87 [(0 : -348 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 348 : 1)] [(840 : 24348 : 1)]
88 [(0 : -352 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 352 : 1)] []
89 [(0 : -356 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 356 : 1)] [(-7632/169 : 408884/2197 : 1)]
90 [(0 : -360 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 360 : 1)] [(-36 : 288 : 1)]
91 [(0 : -364 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 364 : 1)] [(-455/9 : -1547/27 : 1), (273/4 : -5369/8 : 1)]
92 [(0 : -368 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 368 : 1)] [(48 : 496 : 1)]
93 [(0 : -372 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 372 : 1)] []
94 [(0 : -376 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 376 : 1)] [(25200 : 4000376 : 1)]
95 [(0 : -380 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 380 : 1)] []
96 [(0 : -384 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 384 : 1)] [(-48 : 192 : 1)]
97 [(0 : -388 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 388 : 1)] [(280/9 : 11476/27 : 1)]
98 [(0 : -392 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 392 : 1)] [(60 : 608 : 1)]
99 [(0 : -396 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 396 : 1)] []
100 [(0 : -400 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 400 : 1)] []
```

A conjecture that the torsion group is always isomorphic to $C_3$ when $n$ is not twice a cube sounds reasonable. Excepting that case, when the curve has rank greater than 0 we get infinitely many rational solutions but not necessarily integral ones. The sequence of $n$ so that the rank is not 0 matches [the sequence of integers which are the sum of two rational cubes](https://oeis.org/A228499) but not cubes or twice cubes themselves. From here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Good stuff! It sure looks like it might be a well studied family of elliptic curves. Mind you, the equation you described does not give the minimal Weierstrass model. Feeding the coefficients to LMFDB gives these pieces of information with [n=1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/27/a/4), [n=2](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/36/a/4) and [n=3](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/243/b/2) respectively. Observe that LMFDB automagically first converts to the minimal model.

Comment: But, I should *really* learn SAGE one of these years :-)